# Acessing a 64 bit processor register (only reading it's value)

Tags: c++, assembly

I'm wondering if there's a way in which I can read current value of a 64 bit register, using C#/c++, or can it be done only via asm? I don't need to do anything with it, just read the value.

I found the following code (I know it's for a 32 bit register):

```
int data = 0;   
__asm
{
mov ebx, 30
mov data, ebx
}
cout<<data;
```

but after compiling it, 0 is returned. Thank you for any help.

EDIT: I managed to write something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

extern "C" int GetValueRAX();
extern "C" int GetValueRBX();
extern "C" int GetValueRCX();
extern "C" int GetValueRDX();

int main()
{

while (!_kbhit()){

    cout << "RAX: " << GetValueRAX() << endl;
    cout << "RBX: " << GetValueRBX() << endl;
    cout << "RCX: " << GetValueRCX() << endl;
    cout << "RDX: " << GetValueRDX() << endl;
    Sleep(2000);
    system("CLS");
}

return 0;
}
```

And then the asm file:

```
.code
GetValueRAX proc
mov rax, rax
ret
GetValueRAX endp
GetValueRBX proc
mov rax, rbx
ret
GetValueRBX endp
GetValueRCX proc
mov rax, rcx
ret
GetValueRCX endp
GetValueRDX proc
mov rax, rdx
ret
GetValueRDX endp
end
```

But it seems the values don't refresh, as in after the first time the loop calls these procedures, nothing changes after, even if I change the value in register meanwhile. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please specify what compiler you are using.

Comment: Well first off, inline assembly isn't supported for 64-bit code (assuming you're using visual studio)

Comment: @Jester I'm using VS 2013.

DrewMcGowen alright, so I guess asm it is, could you please post an example how do I read a value from that register? Thank you

Comment: Why do you want to do that anyway? Can't it be accomplished in an easier way?

Comment: I don't know if it can be done easier way, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: You don't know what's going to be in the register anyway, since the compiler can use it for whatever it wants.

Comment: @Jester I'm not using the value in the register for anything. I just want to know what value there is in there, sort of like monitoring what is going on in the register.

Comment: @Januszoff why are you doing this though?  It's not going to give you any meaningful results...  the EBX is just a general purpose register used for whatever.

Comment: You know about Debug > Windows > Registers (in visual studio), right?

Comment: You could use `GetThreadContext` but you need to do that from a different thread.

Comment: @mbgda I'm trying to write a very simple register monitor, for four registers, rax;rbx;rcx;rdx. I know it won't be anything usefull, it's just for the sake of practice. Maybe I'm wording my problem badly(English not my first lang), but when I search for anything with register reading in [insert programming language], it just points me to operations on windows registry :(

Comment: @Jester I don't think you'll get values of 64-bit registers that way if your process is 32-bit(x86).

Comment: There's a **huge** difference in doing this in c++ vs c#... I can't think of any way this is meaningful in c#

Comment: @MarcGravell I only stated the languages I'm familiar with. I can look into doing this in asm also, but as said in previous comment, can't find anything while searching, probably becasue I'm wording it wrong.

If anyone would be kind enough to post a asm code that does only one thing, prints the value of whichever of those registers onto screen(console) I can work from there. Thank you.

Comment: "even if I change the value in register meanwhile"... how are you doing this?  From another function written in assembler?  But register values are supposed to be saved and restored across function calls, either you're doing that right and your change has no effect, or you're breaking the call contract and inviting a crash.

Comment: @Januszoff this is plainly impossible on any level at all. Assume you did, indeed, write such a register monitor - _Then the mere sequence of calls and returns that lead you from **there** to **displaying on-screen** would alter R[ABCD]X's value! Moreover interrupts and context switches tamper with them too!_

Comment: I know next to nothing about asm, that's why I asked for an example line of code, 10 posts in and people still are asking why am I doing that, even tho I answered that, and that was not my question. 

So, maybe like this:

Does the above code work? I mean does it really monitor the registers values, or does it not work, takes register values once and then displays them over and over?

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist Will it work for any other register, or is it true for all of them?

Comment: @Januszoff I believe a good starting point for you to learn ASM would be to learn about the "protocol" to call a function in assembler. These protocols are named _calling conventions_ and they specify a) a sequence of steps that you follow to call a function and b) The way in which arguments are placed in registers and on the stack at the moment the calling function hands over to the called function. Read up about the [x86 calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#Microsoft_x64_calling_convention) on Wikipedia for a nice introduction. 64-bit x86 is quite easy.

Comment: @Januszoff Long story short, every time a function call is made (like when `main` calls your `GetValueRAX()`), the calling function (`main`) sets up the registers correctly for the call and transfers control to the called function (`GetValueRAX`), which when it returns leaves the return value in RAX. This setup destroys so many registers it's not even funny. MSDN couldn't possibly be clearer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t169e9c.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zthk2dkh.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7572ztz4.aspx).

Comment: Tag which compiler you are using

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist Ok, that's some helpful material, thanks.

Just one more question: is this program doable in pure asm? Or will there be problems similar to this one?

Comment: @Januszoff Can we discuss it [in chat, here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68688/discussion-between-iwillnotexist-idonotexist-and-januszoff)?

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist says I need 20 rep to chat, can't type anything.